# Sencha Touch 2 horizontal scroll for panel makes it disappear

Tags: sencha-touch-2, panel, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to display some html (album) in a panel and wants to give it a horizontal scroll. But its not showing. It makes my panel disappear. I have spent hours to fix it. Please help me .

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {

        scrollable: {
            direction: 'horizontal',
            directionLock: true
        },
        height:120,
        html: '<h2>Photo Albums</h2><ul><li><a href="#" onclick=""><img src="http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/eventprovider/1/_@user_40285.jpg" title="Cover Photos"></a><span>Cover Photos</span></li><li><a href="#" onclick=""><img src="http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/eventprovider/1/_@user_40285.jpg" title="holilongnameofholitotesthere"></a><span>sample</span></li><li><a href="#" onclick=""><img src="http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/eventprovider/1/_@user_251.jpg" title="Kerala"></a><span>Kerala</span></li><li><a href="#" onclick=""><img src="http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/eventprovider/1/_@user_40285.jpg" title="Kerala"></a><span>Kerala</span></li><li><a href="#" onclick=""><img src="http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/eventprovider/1/_@user_40285.jpg" title="Kerala"></a><span>444</span></li><li><a href="#" onclick=""><img src="http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/eventprovider/1/_@user_40285.jpg" title="Kerala"></a><span>333</span></li><li><a href="#" onclick=""><img src="http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/eventprovider/1/_@user_40285.jpg" title="Kerala"></a><span>222</span></li><li><a href="#" onclick=""><img src="http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/eventprovider/1/_@user_102517.jpg" title="Kerala"></a><span>sample</span></li></ul>',
        });
    // add the list as an item to the viewport
    Ext.Viewport.add({
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            pack: 'center'
        },
        items: [panel
        ]
    });
```

Comment: if u are trying to create a horizontal list, refer the horizontal list example in sencha

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use the `Ext.List` component with some extra CSS.

Here is the JavaScript (very simple list with data):

```
Ext.application({
    launch : function () {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'list',
            data: [
                { name: 'one' },
                { name: 'two' },
                { name: 'three' },
                { name: 'four' },
                { name: 'five' }
            ],
            itemTpl: '{name}'
        });
    }
});
```

And the custom CSS, which makes each item inline:

```
.x-list .x-list-inner {
    width: auto;
}
.x-list-container {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.x-list-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
}
```

You can find out more information about this here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?181298-Dataview-List-Horizontal-Scroll-Possible